# Split single column via a condition creating a new pandas DataFrame with two columns

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to take a single column containing values, split via a condition into two columns, and then generate the pmf for those distributions and plot as a histogram.

Given a column `a` what is the best way to split the column via a condition creating a new dataframe with the resulting 2 columns?

```
import numpy as np
df = DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 4), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

I tried to create a new DataFrame using the filtered Series of the original.. but this doesn't seem to work:

```
DataFrame([df2[df2.a> 0.5].a, df2[df2.a <= 0.5].a], columns=("a_gt", "a_lt"))
```

Comment: As the columns may have different length, how would your resulting df look like?

Comment: The goal is to plot the columns as a histogram.  I don't suppose it's necessary that they are two columns, but this seems to be the *easiest* format for the `.hist()` method to consume.

Comment: To answer your question, it doesn't matter, they could be filled with nulls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use join, but it really depends on what sort of result your looking for.

Create a joined DataFrame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(loc=.5,scale=.2,size=(1000, 4)), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

df1 = pd.DataFrame(df[df.a> 0.5].a)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df[df.a<= 0.5].a)

dfjoined = df1.join(df2, lsuffix='_gt', rsuffix='_lt', how='outer')
```

Plot on the same axis:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)

ax.hist(dfjoined.a_gt, bins=10,range=(0,1), color='r')
ax.hist(dfjoined.a_lt, bins=10,range=(0,1), color='b')
```

[image]

I think the current hist() implementation in Pandas lacks good control over the bin size and range (?), so i have used the histogram function of matplotlib. Numpy also has a histogram function.

Comment: thanks!  I'd like to use the `.hist()` method to plot the distributions for the two a_gt, and a_lt.  Is there a way that his can easily be plotted on a shared axis for those two columns?